# How do I add new code activities to rehosted workflow in WF4.5?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

How do I add code activies to my hosted workflows in WF4.5?  I know that when I create a new workflow application in VS, then hit F6 to compile it, it shows up in the toolbox.  But with out creating an assembly that one of my users would have to import, how do I create a toolbox [code] activity in WF4.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an article that discusses loading custom activities into the toolbox on a rehosted WF4 application: http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/12/23/rehosting-the-workflow-designer-in-wf4.aspx